# mySQL: SUM a column based on another column's entry

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one is users and one is user_answers.

A user can take a survey.  The survey has a leading question which determines the following question set. If the user wants to change their question set before completing, they can go back and re-answer.

The problem I'm having is that I can't get MYSQL to tally the results accurately.  So far I have this:

```
select q_id, 
sum(IF(answer like '%A%',1,0)) as A, 
sum(IF(answer like '%B%',1,0)) as B, 
sum(IF(answer like '%C%',1,0)) as C, 
sum(IF(answer like '%D%',1,0)) as D,
sum(IF(answer like '%E%',1,0)) as E,
sum(IF(answer like '%F%',1,0)) as F
from user_answers as t1
join 
(   select distinct id,`date`
    from users
    WHERE finished = 1
    AND date BETWEEN "2015-09-04" AND "2015-09-10"  
) inr
on inr.id=t1.user_id
group by q_id;
```

This gives me the counts of all user's answers in a nice columned rubric.
But some people changed their leading question ( q_id=0 ), and this script is still counting their answers to other question sets they completed.  A person could answer all 0-11(stored in the same table), but I only want to sum whatever chunk they chose based on question 0.

If I were to pseudo write this terribly in another language, I would do it like:

```
foreach(user_id){
  $result = mysqlfetch(select * from user_answers where uid=user_id and q_id=0);
  if(this.q_id(0).response = A){
    //questions 1-4 get added to tally
  }
  if(this.q_id(0).response = B){
    //questions 5-8 get added to tally
  }
  if(this.q_id(0).response = C){
     //questions 9-11 get added to tally
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to conditionally SUM in the mysql script based on the user's q_0 response when they haven't even been joined yet, in my example.
Sorry for messed up table, I didn't foresee this being a problem for writing a script.

Comment: What exactly does `user_answers.answer` contain?  In particular, why the pattern match `answer LIKE '%A%'` rather than a straightforward equality `answer = 'A'`?

Comment: For most answers it contains a simple character, but some are multiple choice which get concatenated like A,C,D,F so they still get a tally if the character appears in the answer

Comment: But question 0 is only ever a single character?

Comment: You might consider normalising `answer`, e.g. have multiple records in `user_answers` when `(user_id, q_id)` has multiple responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a table to hold your tally criteria:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE answers_to_tally (
     answer0 CHAR(1),
     q_id    INT
   );

   INSERT INTO answers_to_tally
     (answer0, q_id)
   VALUES
     ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('A', 3), ('A', 4),
     ('B', 5), ('B', 6), ('B', 7), ('B', 8),
     ('C', 9), ('C',10), ('C',11)
   ;
   ```
2. By joining that table with your `user_answers` table, you can obtain a set of `(user_id, q_id)` pairs indicating which questions should be tallied for which users:

   ```
   SELECT   a.user_id, t.q_id
   FROM     user_answers     AS a
       JOIN answers_to_tally AS t ON a.answer = t.answer0
                                 AND a.q_id   = 0
   ```
3. The whole shebang can then be put together like this:

   ```
   SELECT   q_id,
            SUM(FIND_IN_SET('A', answer) > 0) AS A,
            SUM(FIND_IN_SET('B', answer) > 0) AS B,
            SUM(FIND_IN_SET('C', answer) > 0) AS C,
            SUM(FIND_IN_SET('D', answer) > 0) AS D,
            SUM(FIND_IN_SET('E', answer) > 0) AS E,
            SUM(FIND_IN_SET('F', answer) > 0) AS F
   FROM     user_answers NATURAL JOIN (
              SELECT   a.user_id, t.q_id
              FROM     user_answers     AS a
                  JOIN users            AS u ON a.user_id = u.id
                  JOIN answers_to_tally AS t ON a.answer  = t.answer0
                                            AND a.q_id    = 0
              WHERE    u.finished = 1
                   AND u.date BETWEEN '2015-09-04' AND '2015-09-10'
            ) x
   GROUP BY q_id
   ```

Comment: This certainly did something!  I'm still looking it over on my end, my number totals are still not making much sense but that could be a database entry issue

Comment: @Kiwizoom: Note that I accidentally omitted `> 0` inside `SUM()`—fixed in my updated answer, but maybe you've not seen that yet?

Comment: I didn't, that fixed the concatenated results I think.  Still looking at my other counts xD  all the responses for each group (besides concatenated) should come out to the same number but they are +-30 which ain't a good sign for me

Comment: @Kiwizoom: I also removed `DISTINCT` from the join with `users`, perhaps naively assuming that `id` was the PK of that table (and that it therefore didn't matter).

Comment: you're right, they're distinct, I might have done that as a precaution. edit: nevertheless my counts changed again?

Comment: @Kiwizoom: Maybe `(user_id, q_id)` is not unique in `user_answers`?  For example, if someone goes back and answers q3 a second time, does it post a second record in for that user/question combination?

Comment: No, if the answer already exists it should be overwritten, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Kiwizoom: That's alright; I was just speculating over why you're seeing strange results.  Maybe they have left some questions unanswered?

Comment: I appreciate it.  I'll have to send to client soon and this makes me feel weird.  I really appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks, I realized I was adding some things incorrectly, this produced the counts I was looking for.   Another crisis averted.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can just join in the information, with another aggregation:

```
select t1.q_id, 
       sum(t1.answer like '%A%') as A, 
       sum(t1.answer like '%B%') as B, 
       sum(t1.answer like '%C%') as C, 
       sum(t1.answer like '%D%') as D, 
       sum(t1.answer like '%E%') as E, 
       sum(t1.answer like '%F%') as F
from user_answers t1 join 
     (select distinct id, `date`
      from users
      where finished = 1 and date BETWEEN '2015-09-04' AND '2015-09-10' 
     ) inr
     on inr.id = t1.user_id join
     user_answers q0
     on q0.user_id = t1.user_id and q0.q_id = 0
where (q0.response = 'A' and t1.q_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)) or
      (q0.response = 'B' and t1.q_id in (5, 6, 7, 8)) or
      (q0.response = 'C' and t1.q_id in (9, 10 11)) 
group by t1.q_id;
```

Some people might prefer to put the logic in the last `on` clause rather than the `where` clause.  This is strictly a matter of preference.  I like to see more complex logic in the `where`.

Note:  you still might not get the results that you want.  The `inr` subquery might return duplicates, if a user is recorded on more than one date.  Either remove `date` from the subquery or include it in the outer `group by`, if this is an issue.

Comment: I'm trying to sample this one, but it keeps saying 'q_id in field list is ambiguous', I think it's something to do with the added queries not stacking right because when I remove lower portions it runs okay

Comment: @Kiwizoom . . . Ooops.  The columns in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` needed to be qualified.